# custom function too slow

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created a custom function that is used in a query. The function opens a small table (50 cells) and adds a date to one column in the query based on lookup results. The function performs too slowly though and I think it may be because I open and close the record set for every record in the query. Is there a way to avoid opening the record set and closing it every time the function is called? I suspect this defeats the purpose of using a function in the first place but am hoping someone has a solution.

**Added after original post.**

Based on the structures below, I need to get the Description from the table into the CustomFunctionField in the query and the date fields are the connection. The table holds the date range and the query has specific dates in the date range.

--Query--
ID | Info | Date | CustomFunctionField

--Table--
ID | StartDate | EndDate | Description

Following is the code:

```
Public Function SelectTerm(DateFull)

    Dim rstin As DAO.Recordset
    Dim dx As Date
    Dim dterm As String

    Set rstin = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTerms", dbOpenSnapshot)

    dx = "1/1/2000"

    If Not rstin.EOF And Not rstin.BOF Then
        Do Until rstin.EOF Or dx >= DateFull
            dx = rstin.Fields("DateEnd")
            rstin.MoveNext
        Loop

        rstin.MovePrevious
        dterm = rstin.Fields("Description")
        rstin.Close
    End If

    SelectTerm = dterm

End Function
```

Comment: Please post the code, there might be improvements that can be made which would be easier if the code was available.

Comment: how many records are in your main query?  Is it possible to use a dlookup to find the value you are looking for?

Comment: A custom function sounds like a particularly bad way to update a table. Custom functions have their uses, but IMHO, they should be avoided in queries, if possible.

Comment: I am fairly sure you could get a pure sql solution, which would be much faster. Please post a little sample data and the sql of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery to look up the term description from `tblTerms` based on a Date/Time field, `DateFull`, in your main table.

```
SELECT
    y.DateFull,
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 [Description]
        FROM tblTerms
        WHERE DateEnd <= y.DateFull
        ORDER BY DateEnd DESC
    ) AS term_description
FROM YourTable AS y;
```

Correlated subqueries aren't exactly known for blazing performance.  However, this approach should be much faster than a UDF which opens a recordset and moves through the rows until it finds the value you want.

Comment: Thanks HansUp. With a few changes, that does produce workable results. I switched the "<=" to ">=" and switched the order by to ASC. I see now that I could have alternately changed "DateEnd" to "DateStart" and it would have corrected the issue also. Thanks.

Comment: OK.  When I submitted that answer, I didn't know tblTerms included both DateStart and DateEnd fields.  In that case, I think you should look into a criterion such as `DateFull BETWEEN DateStart AND DateEnd`.  That could be faster still.

Comment: Actually I would consider a DLookup expression instead of the correlated subquery: `DLookup("[Description]", "tblTerms", Format(DateFull, "\#yyyy-m-d\#") & " BETWEEN DateStart AND DateEnd") AS term_description`

Comment: This does not work at the moment but I know that doing this will increase the query result set 10 fold. I can then add criteria to narrow it down again but other calculations performed in the query don't need to be done for all those lines. The solution you gave previously works well. Thanks.